# 何にもありません vs. 何もありません

Tags: nuances, particle-に

Consider a simple dialogue from [here](https://youtu.be/c4tkvzaufuA?t=89)

> 家もありません 家もありません
>
> ベッドもありません お金も
>
> 家もベッドもありません
>
> **何にも**ありません

Here 何にも appears to be spoken with pitch なんにも{HLLL}.

**Question:** Why is なん followed by a に particle here?

In the sentences prior, no に particle was used:

> **家も**ありません 家もありません
>
> **ベッドも**ありません お金も
>
> **家もベッドも**ありません

though could it have been?

And would the original sentence still make sense if it was written as

> **何も**ありません?

without the に particle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This に is not a particle. It's part of the word. See the following definition in [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82/).

> ［副］《「なにも」の撥音添加。あとに打消しの語を伴う》まったく。何一つ。「―わからない」
>
> [補説]「なんに」は「なに」に撥音が加わったものだが、表記は「なにも」と読み誤らないよう「何も」ではなく、「何にも」とした。

She said [なんにも]【HHHH】.  In this case, you are clearing hearing the difference in stress. According to the rule that says the first two morae always differ in pitch, it should be [なんにも]【LHHH】 in theory, but it tends to go up early when the second mora is ん in standard Japanese.